# UWP Input-Output Naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I have already seen [Record input from NAudio WaveIn, and output to NAudio WaveOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694326/record-input-from-naudio-wavein-and-output-to-naudio-waveout?s=1|2.1408) but for some reason the WaveIn and WaveOut classes don't exsist in either UWP or Naudio 1.8. I'm looking to relay audio exactly like that but in UWP and preferably in a similar amount of lines.

Answer (score 1):

In UWP apps the wavein and waveout APIs are not available. You either have to make use of WasapiCapture or use the new UWP AudioGraph APIs which are actually quite nice. If you're a Pluralsight subscriber you can watch the course I made on the AudioGraph APIs which includes demos of how to record audio.